# Proving divisibility when you have an odd factor.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Let n and k be integers with n≥2 and k≥2. 
Prove that if r ∈ $N$ is an odd factor of k then $(n^{k/r} +1) | (n^k +1)$. 
Deduce that if $n^k +1$ is prime, then k is a power of 2.**

Idea: Use induction, but I don't know if I can as n & k are both changing. I must have to use that r is a odd factor of k, but can't see any definition that might help me. Any hints to get me started? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Prove the $n^a+1$ is a factor of $n^{ar}+1$ when $r$ is an odd number.  Use induction on $r$.